# How can I find the drive name Grub is using for booting?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, bootloader

First time asking here (love this forum use it all the time).
Please forgive my poor explanation of what's happening.

I'm trying to boot an Ubuntu ISO from a hard disk. I'm having some issues finding out the drive name (ie. `/dev/nvme0n1`) to use for grub (ie. `hd0,5`). I have 1 NVMe and 2 internal drives & 2 external drives.
I also have dual-booted Windows and Mint on my NVMe.

**So my question is:**
How can I find what drive name grub is using for booting? I've looked at the config file in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and found my boot entries, but I can't seem to find which drive name they're using or their partition name.

I'm editing the file `40_custom` in `/etc/grub.d` and adding the following:

```
# Ubuntu
menuentry 'Ubuntu ISO' {
set isofile='/home/user/Downloads/ubuntu-19.iso'
loopback loop (hd0,5)$isofile
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=${isofile} quiet splash
initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

I'm not sure what to put in place of the drive name (`hd0,5`) to point grub to the ISO file in my `/home/user/Downloads` folder?

Thank you in advance! This community is amazing!

Comment: I often have to experiment. If I have a flash drive plugged in, it changes drive order. You can see drives in grub with c for command line, and then search for files you know in various partitions: `ls` to see drives & partitions & then `ls (hd0,5)/` or whatever you want. Since kernel not loaded, so /home/$USER does not yet exist not sure path is correct. I typically have many ISO, so use a seperate partition. You also can put ISO in /boot as that is mounted path in grub. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot

Comment: I have only been able to get this to work if the .iso is on a different physical device from /.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I've found is to simply boot into GRUB, drop to terminal using `F2`, and then press `Tab` to let auto-completion tell me what I need to know. Note that you'll need to enter edit mode by pressing `e` for `F2` to work.

Example:

```
grub> ls
(hd0,msdos1) (hd0,msdos2)
grub> ls (hd0,msdos2)/home/
user1/ user2/
```

For the sake of completion, I'll include an entry that's currently working on my machine:

```
menuentry "Recovery"{
        set isofile='/iso/linuxmint-19.3-cinnamon-64bit.iso'
        loopback loop (hd0,msdos6)${isofile}
        linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=${isofile} quiet splash
        initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```